# ifconfig and locate command not found, `bash: ifconfig: command not found`

Tags: linux, command, ifconfig, locate

In the Linux-Ubuntu terminal:

- `ifconfig` throws `bash: ifconfig: command not found`
- `locate` command does the same.
- `sudo yum install net-tools` throws: `bash: yum: command not found` as well, but I might also have made a spelling mistake there when I tested it.

What does it mean, do I have to install `ifconfig`? Or are there alternative commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different distributions of linux have different tools to install packages, known as package managers - you need to use the right one for your distribution. Yum is the package manager for Red Hat systems. Instead, you need to use apt, Ubuntu's package manager. Try:

`sudo apt install net-tools locate`

That pattern *should* work for most packages on Ubuntu. `net-tools` is the package which contains ifconfig on Ubuntu. HOWEVER, ifconfig is well out of date and has been for several years. You should use `ip`, which should be installed already in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Install `net-tools` and `mlocate`, on debian based distribution (Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt install net-tools
sudo apt install mlocate
updatedb
```

Answer (score 2):

They are not delivery with the standard module now.

locate need to be installed

```
apt-get install locate
```

ifconfig has been replaced in default package, you can use IP instead, sample command:

```
ip address show

ip link show
```

Otherwise, install the net tools for ifconfig

```
apt-get install net-tools
```

Comment: Right, `ifconfig` is deprecated, throwing `bash: ifconfig: command not found`. As you say it, there is the much clearer

- `ip address` or 
- `ip addr` or 
- `ip a`.

No need to use the `show` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already point at the ip package. I add the "short command" version here, all rewards go to the other answers.

`ifconfig` is deprecated, throwing `bash: ifconfig: command not found`. Now there is the much clearer

- `ip address` or
- `ip addr` or
- `ip a`.